# Linq Query Failed to Merge Two Tables Record

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to merging two linq query by using Concat . But when i compile the query i receive two errors .

**IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Concat(ParallelQuery, IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery**

Second error is **Method all code not return all path value**

Here is my Interface .

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
     UriTemplate = "/TranscationDetails/{Account_Number}")]
        string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number);
```

Here is the Implementation .

```
  public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
        {

            using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
            {

                var DepositQuery = from x in context.Current_Account_Deposit
                                   where x.Account_Number == Convert.ToInt32(Account_Number)
                                   select x;

                var WithdrawQuery = from x in context.Current_Account_Withdraw
                                    where x.Account_Number == Convert.ToInt32(Account_Number)
                                    select x;

                var merge = DepositQuery.Concat(WithdrawQuery);//**Error on this line**


            }

        }
```

Comment: `var merge = DepositQuery.Union(WithdrawQuery);` (available if `Current_Account_Deposit` & `Current_Account_Withdraw` have exactly same structure). Also you need to return a string for `TranscationDetails` method (currently it's missing, or if you return query results use `IQueryable`).

Comment: What result you get with `Union()` method? To perform `Union` both query results must have same column list. If both result sets are different, create `IEnumerable` object with `ToList()`, then use `Union()`.

Comment: i want to select all the record from Current_Account_Deposit and Current_Account_Withdraw tables with account number and then merge them into single query

Comment: Try use `Join` method: `from x in context.Current_Account_Deposit join y in context.Current_Account_Withdraw on x.AccountNumber equals y.AccountNumber where x.Account_Number == Convert.ToInt32(Account_Number) select ...;`

Comment: Is that `Join` method worked already? And what exactly return type you want for `TranscationDetails` method (I assume you want `IQueryable` but you defined it as string)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use 2 separate queries, just build single query by joining 2 tables and select all required properties from result set. Then, you can put it inside `IEnumerable` object and use [JSON serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.serialize(v=vs.110).aspx) to return JSON response from query result:

```
public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
{
     using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
     {
         var CombinedQuery = (from x in context.Current_Account_Deposit
                             join y in context.Current_Account_Withdraw
                             on x.Account_Number equals y.Account_Number
                             where x.Account_Number == Convert.ToInt32(Account_Number)
                             select new { 
                                x.Account_Number,
                                // put other properties here 
                             }).ToList();

         var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

         return js.Serialize(CombinedQuery); // return JSON string
     }
}
```

Comment: Which table properties I have to use ?? Is current account deposit or current account withdraw ??

Comment: In both table I have properties like account number , transaction type , amount, account holder name etc..

Comment: Both table properties may be used, depending on your need. Also you can use `select new { x, y }` if you want to return all results from both tables.

Comment: I want return account number , account holder name, transaction type ,amount from current account deposit and transaction type and amount from current account withdraw.

Comment: Then you can use `select new { x.AccountNumber, x.AccountHolderName, x.TransactionType, x.Amount, y.TransactionType, y.Amount }`. Note that since 2 column group (`TransactionType` & `Amount`) have same name for both tables, you may require additional naming to distinguish them.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help and support.